# Print Maximum List

Tags: algorithm

We are given a set F={a1,a2,a3,…,aN} of N Fruits. Each Fruits has price Pi and vitamin  content Vi.Now we have to  arrange these fruits in such a way that  the list contains prices in ascending order and the list contains vitamins in descending order.

For example::
N=4

Pi: 2 5 7 10

Vi: 8 11 9 2

This is the exact question https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/find-subsequence-of-maximal-length-simultaneously-satisfying-two-ordering-constr/1289#1289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to reduce the problem to [longest increasing subsequent problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).

1. Sort the list according to first criteria [vitamins]
2. Then, find the longest increasing subsequent in the modified list,
   according to the second criteria [price]

This solution is `O(nlogn)`, since both step (1) and (2) can be done in `O(nlogn)` each.

Have a look on the wikipedia article, under [Efficient Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Efficient_algorithms) - how you can implement longest increasing subsequent

**EDIT:**

If your list allows duplicates, your sort [step (1)] will have to sort by the second parameter as secondary criteria, in case of equality of the primary criteria.

**Example** [your example 2]:

```
Pi::99 12 34 10 87 19 90 43 13 78
Vi::10 23 4 5 11 10 18 90 100 65
```

After step 1 you get [sorting when `Vi` is primary criteria, descending]:

```
Pi:: 013 43 78 12 90 87 87 99 10 34
Vi:: 100 90 65 23 18 11 10 10 05 04
```

Step two finds for longest increasing subsequence in Pi, and you get:

```
(13,100), (43,90), (78,65), (87,11), (99,10)
```

as a feasible solution, since it is an increasing subsequence [according to `Pi`] in the sorted list.

P.S. In here I am assuming the increasing subsequence you want is strictly increasing, otherwise the result is `(13,100),(43,90),(78,65),(87,11),(87,10),(99,10)` - which is longer subsequence, but it is not strictly increasing/decreasing according to `Pi` and `Vi`

Comment: :I think it should be longest decreasing subsequence .But does ur above answer,works for example 2

Comment: @JohnGreve: Look at the edit, I clarified it. Note that You are looking for longest increasing subsequence if you sort by `Vi` as primary criteria [descending] and then looking for increasing subsequence according to `Pi`, and you are looking for decreasing subsequence if you do it vise-versa.

Comment: P.S. In here I am assuming the increasing subsequence you want is strictly increasing, otherwise the result is `(13,100),(43,90),(78,65),(87,11),(87,10),(99,10)` - which is longer subsequence, but it is not strictly increasing/decreasing according to `Pi` and `Vi`